# Drupal 8: Turn off a specific view's block cache

Tags: caching, drupal, drupal-8

I wanted to know how to turn off the block caching for all blocks which were created by a view.  I would like to do this from my theme if that is possible.  My preliminary research suggested that using hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter() might be able to accomplish this.

The view I would like to turn off caching for has a machine name of **background_image**.  My theme is named **my_theme**.  I tried this in my_theme.theme but it did not work:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter().
 */
function my_theme_block_view_background_image_alter(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface $block) { 
  $build['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
}
```

I also tried to use a callback:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_block_view_BASE_BLOCK_ID_alter().
 */
function my_theme_block_view_background_image_alter(array &$build, BlockPluginInterface $block) {
  $build['#pre_render'][] = '_background_image_block_pre_render';
}

/**
 * Pre-render callback
 */
function _background_image_block_pre_render(array $build) {
  $build = array(
    '#cache' => array('max-age' => 0),
  );
  return $build;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that I am able to turn off the view's block caching within the Views UI.  It is under Advanced.  Turning it off there fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 in order to disable cache for a specific view

your view > ADVANCED > Caching > None